# Timer.scheduledTimer does not stop onDisappear

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui

I have the following

```
 .onAppear{
                Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 5, repeats: true) { (timer) in
                     self.timer = timer
                
                     //CODE HERE TO RUN
                 }
```

And I also have

```
.onDisappear{
            self.timer?.invalidate()
}
```

at the top of the view I have

```
struct MediaPlayerView: SwiftUI.View {

    @State private var timer: Timer?
}
```

However it seems that the Timer does not stop when the user disappears the screen/view.

I am wondering how can I make it stop?

Comment: Maybe it's because you are not assigning the `timer` variable any value.

Comment: I noticed the issue is only when I close up (swipe up) and then reopen it

Comment: Hi Russel, you need to invalidate the timer when the view disappears.

Answer (score 0):

Your way to assign the timer to the `@State` variable is wrong. The closure is called when the timer fires, in this case after 5 seconds.

Assign it directly

```
.onAppear {
    self.timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 5, repeats: true) { timer in
        print("timer fired")
   }
}
```

---

Consider to use a `Combine` timer.

```
import Combine

@State private var timer: AnyCancellable?
```

---

```
.onAppear {
    self.timer = Timer.publish(every: 5.0, on: .main, in: .common).autoconnect()
}
.onReceive(timer) { date in
   print(timer fired at \(date))
}
.onDisappear{
    self.timer?.cancel()
}
```